# How do I nest an if statement within a function

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

I would like to nest a conditional if statement within a function, but I am not sure what the correct syntax is. Right now I have:

```
def answer_one():

  x=dataframe
  perRenew = x['% Renewable'].mean()
  x['Highrenew'] = 0

    if x['% Renewable'] >= perRenew :
       x['Highrenew'] = 1
    else:
       x['Highrenew'] = 0

  return x
```

But when I run the code I get ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

What are some correct ways/ best practices to get the job done?

Comment: Numpy's 'np.select' might help you, did you check the documentation (or posts on StackOverflow) on that?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you just need

```
df['Highrenew']=(df['% Renewable']>= df['% Renewable'].mean()).astype(int)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `df['% Renewable']`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is python. the indent in the sample code is invalid. the example code below is what I think you are looking for.

```
if a == 1:
  if b == 1:
    pass
  elif:
    pass
```